# compiling raspbian wheezy usb driver ch341.c to ch341.ko

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am supposed to compile /usb/serial/ch341.c file to ch341.ko.
I am using rs485 module which is not working. I found on some forums that other people also facing this problem because drivers come with old device id in ch341.ko file and device comes with new device id -

http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=82078234d4023c61b9d88e8be5e795423d17538e

I need to add new device id to ch341.c file which is alredy there in -

http://lxr.linux.no/linux/drivers/usb/serial/ch341.c

Now i need to compile this file to ch341.ko for raspbian wheezy to work in my raspberry pi.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a CH341A (in SERIAL MODE) attached to my RasPI (raspbian wheezy with latest Upgrades).
To my surprise the CH341A SERIAL was recognized correctly and I communication
through "ttyUSB0" worked fine (using pySerial).

ls /dev/tty*

...look for "ttyUSB0" in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to follow the following blog posts:

1. [Building modules for Raspberry Pi](http://sprabhu.blogspot.in/2012_07_01_archive.html#4273048004731121321)
2. [More specific one on building a wireless driver](http://blog.poettner.de/2012/08/22/how-to-compile-rtl8192cu-ko-for-raspberry-pi-running-raspian/)

Following the steps outlined in these two posts you should be able to compile/ or cross compile your driver and get the required .ko file

Comment: I have checked drivers and device id is correct in it. Also i have tried code on ubuntu with newer ch341 driver, it returns none but drivers are ok. @Nipun